# Python requests hook returns a value to cause exception

Tags: python, python-requests

The [Documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced.html#event-hooks) for python requests module says for hooks that "If the callback function returns a value, it is assumed that it is to replace the data that was passed in. If the function doesn’t return anything, nothing else is effected"

Now i am trying to return a value(int in my case) from my hook function and it throws an exception. This will be valid in all the cases when the return value is an object that DOESNOT have the raw() method defined for it.

Here is some code

```
def hook(resp,**kwargs):
    print resp.url
    return 1

def main()
    s = requests.Session()
    s.hooks = {"response":hook}
    r = s.get("http://localhost/index.html")
```

And here is the exception:

```
http://localhost/index.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/talha/ws/test.py", line 85, in <module>
   main()
 File "/home/talha/ws/test.py", line 72, in main
   r = s.get("http://localhost/index.html")
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 347, in get
   return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 335, in request
   resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 446, in send
   extract_cookies_to_jar(self.cookies, request, r.raw)
 AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'raw'
```

The code in sessions.py @line 446 is trying to extract cookies after the dispatch_hook..From source

```
    # Response manipulation hooks
    r = dispatch_hook('response', hooks, r, **kwargs)

    # Persist cookies
    extract_cookies_to_jar(self.cookies, request, r.raw)
```

Either the documentation needs to change or the handling needs to be re-worked. What is the best way to handle this ?

[update]

Based on the comments I tried to return the base `response` object. Turns out it cannot be used in that manner also since some of its fields are initialized to `None`.

Newer code:

```
def hook(resp, **kwargs):
    obj = requests.Response()
    return obj
```

Exception thrown now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/talha/ws/test.py", line 88, in <module>
   main()
File "/home/talha/ws/test.py", line 75, in main
   r = s.get("http://localhost/index.html")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 347, in get
   return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 335, in request
   resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 446, in send
   extract_cookies_to_jar(self.cookies, request, r.raw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 108, in extract_cookies_to_jar
    res = MockResponse(response._original_response.msg)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_original_response'
```

What seems is that i will have to implement a full pseudo response?

Comment: My expectation would be that the intention is that the callback should return the same type as it receives, so that ultimately it returns a modified "response". Note: I am not a python-requests user, this is just intuition.

Comment: I see no problem; you are given a response object, so whatever you return will replace that response object. The rest of the code still expects the replacement to be a response object, does that really need to be made explicit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the callback function returns a value, it is assumed that it is to replace the data that was passed in. If the function doesn’t return anything, nothing else is effected.

This means that whatever you return is expected to take the place of the response object you were passed.

Nothing in the documentation states that you can return just *anything*. What did you expect to happen instead?

If you wanted to return a response that has different data, return something that acts like a response still. This means that either you need to subclass the `requests` response object, or implement something that provides the same API:

```py
from requests.models import Response

class MyIntResponse(Response):
    def __init__(self, integer):
        super(MyIntResponse, self).__init__()
        self._content_consumed = True
        self._content = integer

def hook(resp,**kwargs):
    print resp.url
    newresp = MyIntResponse(1)
    newresp.raw = resp.raw  # copy across original HTTP response object
```

You may want to copy over some of the other attributes from the original response; check the documentation on what attributes `Response` objects have.

Comment: An improvement could be to set the integer in the `status_code` rather then the `_content`. Thanks btw